# Is it possible to configure how to fold the already created syntax?

Tags: notepad++

For example in C/C++ { } can be folded as in Pascal begin end.

```
void fun() {
 do smth..
}
```

folded in just `void fun() {..}`

Is it possible to configure how to fold the already created syntax?
I want to fold my procs in ASM

```
fun proc
mov eax, 1
ret
fun endp
```

to

```
fun proc .. fun endp
```

Comment: Syntax for asm is already defined by defualt from box with Notepad++. I just want to configurate this. I didn't find anything like that in the asm.xml / langs.xml in Notepad++ folders.

Comment: I think you need to [edit] the question to show examples (in text, not images) of what you want. As it stands I do not understand the question.

Comment: Better. Hopefully someone can help you.